# Is CompletableFuture followed immediately by a get efficient?

Tags: java, asynchronous

I just found the following code, it supplies an asynchronous task but immediately get the result (so if I understand correctly, it blocks the current thread until the result is available).

Is it efficient ?

```
public String myMethod() {
    CompletableFuture<String> futur = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
       // my long call to an external API
       return "theResult";
    });
    
    try {
        return future.get(FUTURE_TIMEOUT_DURATION, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

If the timeout is handled correctly in the call to the external API, do I need this completable futur ?

Is it ok to simplify the code like this ?

```
public String myMethod() {
    // my long call to an external API
    return "theResult";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you doesn't expect any problem with timeout you most probably can remove code related to feature.

There is possibility that code use some threadlocal variables or otherwise relies on being executed in separate thread.